# jsPlumb and Fabric.js integration

Tags: javascript, html, fabricjs, jsplumb

I have built a web application in [fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com/) where the user adds and draws several graphical elements over an originally blank canvas. My application has arrived to the point in which some of these graphical elements need to be interactively connected (i.e. connected by the user using the mouse). I am trying to design the best way to include these connections in the canvas since, due to aesthetic considerations, drawing lines with fabric might not be best solution for this.

I have run into [jsPlumb](http://jsplumbtoolkit.com/demo/home/dom.html) and found several examples of connections between div and other dom elements. My specific question is: Is it possible to use the jsPlumb functionalities within the objects that fabric.js draws in the canvas. If so, does anyone have an example of this? In case this integration between jsPlumb and fabric.js is not possible, what would be the best way to achieve this?

Many thanks to all in advance.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, this integration doesn't make much sense.

Everything that `fabricjs` provides can be done using `jsPlumb', of course animation would require a bit of coding, but it's fairly possible.

Another reason is `fabricjs` deals with canvas, whereas `jsPlumb` deals with DOM elements, their integration would be more pain, than coding the actual requirement entirely in `jsPlumb`.